# What happened in linux bash when I use "cd //"?

Tags: linux, bash

I find an interesting thing about linux bash.
After I typed `cd //` in linux bash.Guess what happend?
The directory became `//`,then I `pwd`,the directory is `//`.
But I don't know what happend to the bash.

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what should have happened.

When you did `cd //`, the system changed your directory to `/`. So pwd will tell you (correctly)  that you are in `//`. (Refer to the answer linked in the comments to understand why multiple slashes are the same as a single slash).

If you do an `ls` after your `cd //` command you'll see a lot of folders that are mounted on `/`.

Nothing 'happened to the bash'.

If you do a `cd` , it will take you back to your more famliar `$home`.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Multiple slashes mean the same as a single slash. But shells are free to store the path as you wrote it for display. Actual `getcwd()` call will return just `/` however.

I'm hoping that answers your question. Otherwise - what's the question you're trying to ask?